# Why does my query break whenever adding a limit clause?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am new to SQL and am currently still learning the basics/trying to get a hold on how everything actually flows and works.

With that being said, attached is an image of a query I am playing around with for practice. The goal is to "find the PID and flight hours logged for the 3 pilots with the most hours in an F-15E."

I have no problem retrievng the info for pilots whom can fly the F-15E, and I imagine with a little more time I would easily be able to find a solution to limiting the returned query.

```sql
SELECT pid, model, HoursLogged
FROM FlightSkills
WHERE Model = 'F-15E'
ORDER BY HoursLogged DESC
LIMIT 3
```

[image]

However, this leads me to the question as to why my query breaks upon adding the LIMIT clause. Am I ordering my statements wrong, or is the problem a little deeper than that? Thank you!

Comment: Please [never post an image of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). I fixed it for you this time. Also, you didn't specify in what way the query "breaks". Can you please describe your exact problem?

Comment: What do you mean by “breaks”? Is there an error (what’s the errors message)? Does it not return the expected values - what did you expect, what did it return?

Answer (score -3):

I ended up using a FETCH clause, I think the LIMIT clause may not have been working because of different versions of SQL.

`FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY` after the ORDER BY.

Comment: you incorrectly tagged mysql , mysql does not have FETCH..and yes different dialects have different ways to limit(or top or fetch)..and are very different in many ways with very little code that can be simply dropped into one dialect from another.